# mono-compiled binaries not runable on Windows (unless msbuild is used)

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, mono

I have some trouble using binaries created by Mono csc compiler on Windows. It's a basic CLI project for Framework 4.0 with a few internal assemblies. Previously, we were building this tool with xbuild and the result was usable everywhere. Now xbuild cannot be used (internal policy reasons) so I added a script which calls csc commands directly. The .exe can still be run in Mono but on Windows I get:

**Method not found: "System.String System.String.TrimEnd(Char)".**
at …

This is surprising. When I investigate that function call in code, it's like:

```
subDirectory.Replace('/', Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).TrimEnd(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)
```

So, that signature is not available in .NET but `.TrimEnd(params Char[])` is. And the compiler should normally convert between a single argument and params array.

My csc command line looks like:

> csc /debug:full /debug:portable /optimize- /define:"DEBUG;TRACE"
> /langversion:latest .v4.0.AssemblyAttribute.cs
> /out:bin/Debug/myproject.exe /target:exe *.cs */*.cs
> /r:bin/Debug/some_custom_depencency.dll
> /r:bin/Debug/some_other_custom_dependency.dll …
> /nostdlib /r:System.dll /r:System.Xml.Linq.dll
> /r:System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll /r:System.Data.dll
> /r:System.Xml.dll /r:System.Core.dll /r:mscorlib.dll   /warn:4

It's more or less the same what msbuild does, just using shell's wildcard expansion. And the  .v4.0.AssemblyAttribute.cs file is the one I grabbed from xbuild temp files (where it defines the .NET Framework version).

I checked the old and new exes (msbuild and custom calls) in dotPeek and everything looks identical except for the signature. File is runnable with Mono itself.

I'm running out of ideas now, can anyone suggest something to try or change or knows the reason immediately?

Comment: For .NET Framework 4.0 projects, you should use the MSBuild 4.0 shipped with .NET Framework 4.0 (part of Windows 8 and above), https://blog.lextudio.com/the-rough-history-of-msbuild-cc72a217fa98 Calling csc and wishing "It's more or less the same what msbuild does" doesn't keep you on the right track.

Comment: Let me repeat: "Now xbuild cannot be used (internal policy reasons)" (and obviously its replacement in mono world, msbuild).

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, it was right upfront. msbuild/xbuild uses absolute paths to the framework assemblies but my call didn't. I assumed that it would consider information from AssemblyAttribute but apparently it doesn't, mono linker happily goes to whatever its default framework is, and is not reporting mismatches at build time.

The solution: change the /r:... paths to the ones in /usr/lib/mono/4.0-api/ (or whatever the framework setting defines).